# check a if a word is contained in a page and store all the results in an ArrayList

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am using Selenium Java Webdriver. I would like to check whether the word "good" is contained in a page and to store every found in an ArrayList.

For example. The page contains the words "good", "goodmorning" and "goodafternoon". Then I should get an ArrayList = [good, goodmorning, goodafternoon].

I think the traditional methods to check whether some text is contained in a page like "contain("")" won't work in this case.

What do you guys say? Can it be done?

Comment: Use regex to check for words containing "good"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what you are looking for, it is using Selenium WebDriver. I tested it on this page for the word "good" and got the expected results.

```
public List<String> perform(String url, String searchWord) {
    // webdriver that opens the given URL
    driver.get(url); 
    searchWord = searchWord.toLowerCase();

    // get the top most element on page, it will be html in most cases
    WebElement html = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("html"));

    // gets all the text on page
    String htmlText = html.getText().replaceAll("\n", " ").toLowerCase();

    // split by space to get all words on page
    String[] allWords = htmlText.split(" ");

    List<String> myWordList = new ArrayList<String>();

    // add all the words that contains your search word
    for (String word : allWords)
        if (word.contains(searchWord))
            myWordList.add(word);

    return myWordList;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
File f = new File ("C:\\yourpath\\filename");    
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f));
                String line = "";
                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                   if (line.matches("good")) // regex here
                    System.out.println(line);
                }
```

Comment: what is "f" in (new FileReader(f));?

Comment: sorry I don't get it. What do you mean with a file? I am using Selenium Webdriver.

Answer (score -1):

You can use Scanner too:

```
    Scanner scanner = null;
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("good[a-zA-Z]*\\p{Blank}*");
    List<String> matches = new ArrayList<String>();;
    try {
        scanner = new Scanner(driver.getPageSource());//selenium driver
        String match = "";
        while (null != (match = scanner.findWithinHorizon(pattern, 0))){            
            matches.add(match.trim());
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }finally{
        if(scanner != null){
            scanner.close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I haven't tried the regex so it will probably fail ;)

Comment: where you write "your//path", I should introduce the same expression that I use for the xpaths right? in my case is something like that //tr/td[7]/div/a

Comment: and what exactly is the list where the information was stored?

Comment: it says "Unreachable catch block for FileNotFoundException. This exception is never thrown from the try statement body". It finds an error in catch (FileNotFoundException e)

Comment: it seems to compile, but in the page there are only one  "Change Manager 20" and one "Change Manager" (good, goodmornig... were just examples). But I am getting the ArayList like that:
[Change Manager, Change Manager, Change Manager, Change Manager, Change Manager, Change Manager, Change Manager, Change Manager, Change Manager, Change Manager, Change Manager]

Comment: Inspect getPageSource() output String, i suppose a debug would help